# Moving an object in a straight line

Tags: javascript, html, translation, move

I want to move an object (a little cat for example) along a line. I don't know how to use functions like `move.object` or `transform.translate` ... Please help me.
Here, the starting of my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
<script>      
function dessinerLigne(ax, ay, bx, by) {
    if (ay > by) {
        bx = ax + bx;
        ax = bx - ax;
        bx = bx - ax;
        by = ay + by;
        ay = by - ay;
        by = by - ay;
    }
    var calc = Math.atan((ay - by) / (bx - ax));
    calc = (calc * 180) / Math.PI;
    var length = Math.sqrt((ax - bx) * (ax - bx) + (ay - by) * (ay - by));
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='ligne' style='height:" + length + "px;width:1px;background-color:black;position:absolute;top:" + (ay) + "px;left:" + (ax) + "px;transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);-ms-transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);transform-origin:0% 0%;-moz-transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);-moz-transform-origin:0% 0%;-webkit-transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);-webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;-o-transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);-o-transform-origin:0% 0%;'></div>"
}


var pointB: (1055, 105);

function Start() {
    var pointA = transform.position(585, 890);
    while (true) {
        yield MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, 3.0);
        yield MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, 3.0);
    }
}

function MoveObject(thisTransform: Transform, startPos: Vector3, endPos: Vector3, time: float) {
    var i = 0.0;
    var rate = 1.0 / time;
    while (i < 1.0) {
        i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
        thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
        yield;
    }
}
</script>    
</head>
<body onload="dessinerLigne(1055,105,585,890);">
</body>
<body background="map.jpg"></body>
</html>`enter code here`
```

Comment: to move an object along a line (two point/vectors) simply do transform.translate((startPos - endPos) * deltaTime) and call it every update.

Comment: That's what I do but it isn't work ... So if I understand, I need to write "var startPos = (1055,105) var endPos = (585, 890)" and that's it ?

Comment: That's just to define the two positions, subtraction styartPos from endPos gives a direction for the cube to travel in (velocity) and multiply by delta to give it real-time movement. If it doesn't work, what does it show, does it not move or does it fly off?

Comment: I see, the problem is your moving it to point B slowly, then slowly back to point B, but during that time you aren't allowing for rendering, so really your moving it to b then back to A before it can render, so instead of having a while loop swith the moveObjects, you need to use an update method that updates everything even rendering. Basicly don't have a while loop (`while(true) move move`) and have the move move in an update function and not start that is only called once.

Comment: I have only the background image

Comment: Then how do you know if the object is mnoving or not?

Comment: That's the problem ... It's not work ...

Comment: I don't understand? so you dont have a way to se if it moves?

Comment: I refresh my html page to see if it work. On my background image, I start to trace a line, and it's work, and then, when I add the function to make move an image in png format, the line is disappear and nothing move

Comment: that is because a while loop stop anything else from running and when using while(true) it runs forever stopping anything else.

Comment: So my code it isn't complete ?

Comment: not entirely, its complete but not structured right. google any starter game making tutorial in java and the first thing they'll do is create an update method, which is what you need.

Comment: as a suggestion why you don't use jquery animate to easily simulate movement?

Comment: I don't know what is it, I'm new on programmation, and I misunderstand a lot of thing about it ...